# navigator.share(file) doesnt work for audio files

Tags: javascript, web-share

I have this working function:

```
export const shareFile = (message: File) => {
      const nav = window.navigator as any ;
      const data = { files: [message], text: '' };
      if (nav.canShare && nav.canShare(data)) {
        navigator.share(data)
        .then(() => console.log('Share was successful.'))
        .catch(error => console.log('Sharing failed', error));
      } else {
        console.log(`Your system doesn't support sharing files.`);
      }
    };
  };
```

It works perfectly for txt files, videos and images, but not for audio files (e.g .mp3 file). when i log the file this is its properties:

```
 file:
data: File
lastModified: 1619510595837
lastModifiedDate: Tue Apr 27 2021 11:03:15 GMT+0300 (Israel Daylight Time) {}
name: "feature-completion-1.mp3"
size: 4015
type: "audio/mpeg"
webkitRelativePath: ""
__proto__: File
```

And in the console the error is:
`Sharing failed DOMException: Permission denied`

Can someone please help me solve this problem? why is Permission denied?

Note: my website is served on HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is correct, but you’re running into a security restriction. The spec explains this in [step 9](https://w3c.github.io/web-share/#share-method) of the processing algorithm for the `share()` method:

*If a file type is being blocked due to security considerations, return a promise rejected with a `"NotAllowedError"` `DOMException`.*

Now you can argue of course why `.mp3` files would be a security issue (I don't know the answer). Ideally you do this in a [new.crbug.com](https://new.crbug.com/).